# Como puedo sumar mis registros con eloquent? Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

tengo que hacer una sentencia con eloquent que me liste todos los registros creados hoy y sumarlos... los registros deben estar agrupados por usuario... Es una sentencia simplemente para saber cuanto vendio un usuario en el dia,
La sentencia ya lo tengo en sql crudo por asi decirlo pero no se como traspasarlo a eloquent,
esta es la sentencia que necesito pero con eloquent

```
$ventas = DB::select("SELECT u.id, SUM(v.total) as total, v.idusuario, u.usuario FROM ventas as v, users as u WHERE LEFT(fecha_hora,10)=CURDATE() and v.estado = 'Registrado' and v.idusuario = u.id GROUP BY v.idusuario, u.usuario")
```

Y esto asi lo estoy tratando de traspasar

```
$ventas = Venta::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ventas.idusuario')
        ->select('ventas.idusuario', 'users.usuario', 'ventas.total', 'ventas.fecha_hora')
        ->whereDay('ventas.fecha_hora', date('d'))
        ->paginate(3);
```

Si me preguntan porque simplemente no uso la sentencia que ya esta completa, es porque no puedo usar la paginacion con ese metodo.. lei porque eso devuelve una coleccion y el paginate no funciona asi.. este es mi controlador

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $buscar = $request->buscar;
    $criterio = $request->criterio;

    if ($buscar==''){
        $ventas = Venta::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ventas.idusuario')
        ->select('ventas.idusuario', 'users.usuario', 'ventas.total', 'ventas.fecha_hora')
        ->whereDay('ventas.fecha_hora', date('d'))
        ->paginate(3);
    }
    else{
        $ventas = Venta::where($criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    }


    return [
        'pagination' => [
            'total'        => $ventas->total(),
            'current_page' => $ventas->currentPage(),
            'per_page'     => $ventas->perPage(),
            'last_page'    => $ventas->lastPage(),
            'from'         => $ventas->firstItem(),
            'to'           => $ventas->lastItem(),
        ],
        'ventas' => $ventas
    ];
}
```

Comment: ¿qué significa: _que me **estire** todos los registros creados hoy_?

Comment: Que me traiga una  lista de los registros creados hoy.. ahora edito la pregunta